# how to execute redis command in shell

Tags: shell, redis

all:
   I want to operate redis in my shell,my locate redis ip:127.0.0.1 port:6379,i want to insert data to the redis in my shell,but i don't know how to operate redis in my own shell,is there any redis command like mysql -e to execute in the shell directly.

Answer (score 42):

Please note that Konstantin’s answer is better.

Just use `echo` with `redis-cli` like this:

```
# Delete list of cores
echo DEL cores | redis-cli

# Add a new core to the list of cores
echo LPUSH cores 1 | redis-cli 

# Wait forever for a core to become available
echo BLPOP cores 0 | redis-cli
```

Comment: hi,Mark :why tells me command not found.the code is :echo set 1 2 | redis-cli   ,but when i use ./redis-cli  i can connect the redis,echo set 1 2|.redis-cli ,also not work

Comment: I guess `redis-cli` is not on your PATH - where did you install it to? See if you can find its full path with something like `find /usr -name "redis-cli"` then use the full path, e.g. `echo ... | /usr/local/bin/redis-cli`

Comment: redis-cli -h 10.162.49.104 PING

Comment: @shenyan is right.  redis-cli has the capacity to accept commands as parameters.  Don't make your OS spawn a process just to type in a command.  Recommend upvoting Konstantin's answer.

Comment: How to do this with authentication (username/password)?

Answer (score 18):

It's is simpler to call commands directly, without pipelines:

```
> redis-cli -n 0 LPUSH mylist "hello"
(integer) 1
```

Be shure that you pass `-n` option, it's like mysql `use <database>` statement, it's set used database (first index is zero). When you run command from cli redis don't uses default database. To get information about databases which has some keys use command:

```
> INFO keyspace
db0:keys=4,expires=0,avg_ttl=0
```

More options here: https://redis.io/topics/rediscli

Comment: For anyone looking to talk to a remote redis host using hostname

redis-cli -c -h <hostname> SADD mykey "text"

Comment: Thanks! Also be sure to add quotes around values you pass to the redis command. I was struggling with the key listing command `KEYS *`. I made it work by adding quotes around the asterisk: `redis-cli -n 0 KEYS "*"`